# MVC2 renders previous value while chaining item in for loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, render, keep-alive

I have list within a model and i bind it through the loop to the Text Box. If I change    the      number of items in the list, it renders the previous value. Following is the code

```
<%  for (int j = 0; j < Model.HRMColumnMapping.LstHRMColumnMapping.Count; j++)
  {%>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <%=Html.Hidden("HRMColumnMapping.LstHRMColumnMapping[" + j + "].TableID",
 Model.HRMColumnMapping.LstHRMColumnMapping[j].TableID.ToString())%>
         <%=Html.Hidden("HRMColumnMapping.LstHRMColumnMapping[" + j + "].ColumnID", 
Model.HRMColumnMapping.LstHRMColumnMapping[j].ColumnID.ToString())%>
         <%=Html.Hidden("HRMColumnMapping.LstHRMColumnMapping[" + j + "].ColumnName", 
Model.HRMColumnMapping.LstHRMColumnMapping[j].ColumnName.ToString())%>
         <%=Html.Encode(Model.HRMColumnMapping.LstHRMColumnMapping[j].ColumnName)%>
       </td>
       <td>
        <%=Html.TextBox("HRMColumnMapping.LstHRMColumnMapping[" + j + "].SourceColumnName",
            Model.HRMColumnMapping.LstHRMColumnMapping[j].SourceColumnName, 
            new { @class = "required", 
                  @style = "width:250px; min-width:350px;", maxlength = 500 
                })%>
       </td>
   </tr>
  <% } %>
```

If I change the value of the text (fetch different value from controller

Comment: Where is the code? Please edit your post. Read: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
that is
 ModelState.Clear(); in controller